# Raster Vertical Projection ArcGIS Pro v3.1.2

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, wgs84, vertical-transformation

I'm trying to do a vertical coordinate system transformation on a raster, from WGS84 to NAVD88. I have downloaded and installed the appropriate coordinate systems package but cannot accomplish this using the "project raster" tool. From what I gather this feature was unavailable on v2.9 and prior. Has Esri just neglected to patch this or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclosure: I work for Esri.

The first FAQ is outdated. The Project Raster tool does support vertical transformations. There's a "vertical" checkbox that you must select to enable the functionality (the joys of backwards-compatibility!).

As the OP stated, you do HAVE to install the ArcGIS Coordinate System Data setup ("CSD") to access the geoid models and other files needed for most of the vertical transformations. (see Note at bottom)

I suspect you left the output geographic coordinate system as WGS84. That's not going to work as NAVD88 doesn't exist in connection to WGS84. Set the output horizontal coordinate system to NAD 1983 (2011).

I'm not at work to double-check, but the transformation path will have at least two steps if the input heights are ellipsoidal: WGS84 to NAD 1983 (2011) (ellipsoidal heights) and then a transformation from NAD 1983 (2011) to NAVD88 using Geoid12b or Geoid18. the "geoid" models published by NGS do convert from ellipsoidal heights to NAVD88 (gravity-related elevations).

Note: CSD also includes all newer geographic/datum transformation files for the last several years, so you should always install it. We won't show/allow transformations that require files in the CSD if it's not installed.

Comment: That worked in two steps! Thanks so much! Ended up being off by only about 1cm in the z, I think that's pretty good all things considered.

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS will not do vertical datum transformations on raster data.  See [FAQ: Is there a geoprocessing tool to transform the vertical datum of raster elevation values in ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro?](https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/faq-is-there-a-geoprocessing-tool-to-transform-the-vert-000016918) and [FAQ: How do I apply a vertical datum transformation in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/faq-how-do-i-apply-a-vertical-datum-transformation-in-a-000015147).  Vectorize, transform, rasterize is the Esri method.

I have tried to convert a WGS84 ascii raster to NAVD88 using the downloaded version of [vDatum](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/) but the software never completed the transformation after an overnight spin.

Comment: Still can't transform with this method. I just found the documentation for all available transformations, looks like WGS84 to NAVD88 is not supported. [link](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/mapping/properties/pdf/geographic_transformations.pdf)

Comment: You need to use two transformations. One for WGS84 to Geoid 12b and one from geoid 12b to NAVD88.  I am going to try to tap in @mkennedy for an expert opinion.

Comment: @GBG and DJ-MT somehow the @ didn't work. I'm sorry I didn't see this sooner.